# Issue with List count method

Tags: python, list

The Program I need help is written below

```
def countHits(file):    
        f2 = open(file,'rU')    
        l2 = f2.readlines()    
        f2.close()    
        user_input = raw_input("Enter the URL that you wish to chck fr the nmber of Hits")     
        print "The number of HITS for the given STRING/URL is : %s"%(l2.count(user_input))

def main():    
        strin = raw_input("Enter the file name\n")    
        countHits(strin)

if __name__ == '__main__':

   main()
```

The file given as input contains list of urls (mentioned below):

```
/RLSsdTfswds/images//innercontainer-collapse.gif    
/RL/css/default.css    
/RLSTsdsdRdsdU/scripts/highslide/graphics/outlines/rounded-white.png    
/RLSsdsdTsdsRsddU/scripts/highslide/graphics/zoomout.cur    
/RLS/css/highslide/highslide/graphics/loader.white.gif    
/RL/css/default.css    
/RLST/rws/scripts/processschScript.js    
/RLSR/scripts/NumberFormat.js    
/RL/css/default.css
```

My query is that when I try to find url "/RL/css/default.css", the program doesn't gives me the count. Help me where I'm making a mistake ?

Comment: maybe list element contains `\n` or another endline and your string don't so they aren`t actuually equal

Comment: @ Darth Kotik
I tried printing list elements individually and they don't show a "\n" at the end.

Comment: @Harvey, You could do this for addressed comment: http://i.imgur.com/8eIrY0D.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Possible solution:*

```
def countHits(file):    
    f2 = open(file,'rU')    
    l2 = f2.readlines()    
    f2.close()
    l2 = [l.strip() for l in l2]
    user_input = raw_input(
       "Enter the URL that you wish to chck fr the nmber of Hits"
    )   
    print "The number of HITS for the given STRING/URL is : %s"% (
       l2.count(user_input)
    )
```

I guess this will work faster.

```
def countHits(file):    
    f2 = open(file,'rU')    
    l2 = f2.readlines()    
    f2.close()
    l2 = map(lambda x: x.strip(), l2)
    user_input = raw_input(
       "Enter the URL that you wish to chck fr the nmber of Hits"
    )   
    print "The number of HITS for the given STRING/URL is : %s"% (
       l2.count(user_input)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The following lines can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file;
>   a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string,
>   and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.
>   This makes the return value unambiguous;
>   if f.readline() returns an empty string,
>   the end of the file has been reached,
>   while a blank line is represented by '\n',
>   a string containing only a single newline.

Though, you need to "sanitize" every line which is being read with `file.readlines()`,
like this for instance:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f :
    data = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
```

And `data` will contain the list of lines, without tabs, spaces or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove trailing whitespace from the input.

```python
print "The number of HITS for the given STRING/URL is : %s" % (
   l2.count(user_input.strip())
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using List Comprehension is faster than lambda function.

```
 def countHits(file):
        f2 = open(file,'rU')
        l2 = f2.readlines()
        f2.close()
        user_input = raw_input(
          "Enter the URL that you wish to chck fr the nmber of Hits"
        ) 

        lst = [(s.strip()) for s in l2]
        print "The number of HITS for the given STRING/URL is : %s" % (
           lst.count(user_input.strip())
        )

def main():
        strin = raw_input("Enter the file name\n")
        countHits(strin)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```